# Doing a redirect without using 301 but a PHP script, is that OK?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've been reading about [redirection](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection), and how it can [affect](https://moz.com/blog/301-redirection-rules-for-seo) (or not if done properly) SEO.

I'm changing my website's content platform from Drupal to a PHP custom made code.

In my current site I have two links that point to the same link like this:

> .../node/123
>
> .../my-node-title

Mainly because Drupal allows you to create a custom-made links, so every article has a default one (`node/123`) and the custom-made one (`/my-node-title`).

**My question is about what to do in order to prevent losing any SEO that each link may have.**

In the new website all articles are structured like this: `content.php?id=123`

I've stored in the database the custom-made link of every article.

**Instead of doing a 301 redirect I'm redirecting all links that do not exist to be redirected to redirect.php page to process the request.** There I take the string from the link, look for it in the database and redirect the user.

The process is like this:

### in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./redirect.php
```

In redirect.php:

I grab the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) I get the last part of the link (ie. my-node-title), look for it in the database and grab the ID of the article (ie. 123) and save it in a `$link` variable.

Then I use [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function and do the redirect: `header('Location: '.$link);`

So, people still click on `.../my-node-title` but when the article loads at the navigation bar appears `/content.php?id=123`

**I would like to know your comments about this solution.** I know that with SEO there are not fixed rules, or certainty in anything, but I would like to know if what am I doing is acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde I've read the warning when I was posting it, and it's about how to properly do a redirect, about using the **.htaccess** rule and the php **header()** function correctly, so I think it's allowed and not a pure SEO question.

Comment: So instead of redirecting to your content page, why not just include the content page in your php code?

Comment: @Demodave, you mean adding the redirection in content.php file directly?

Comment: No, don't redirect use include/include_once/require/require_once to include the file into the calling page.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, instead of adding the htaccess rule, I could just include the php file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SEO strategy should not only focus on discoverability of your pages, but also take proper UX into account. Having a user follow /some-link/, and then landing on /index.php?page_id=123 may disorient them.

As for saving your ranking, a 302 redirect (which is what the 'Location' header does in PHP), will not affect PageRank, [according to Google](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC). I have no information on how it might adversely affect other ranking signals. You would probably do good to specify a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) for all distinct links that point to the same resource.

Also, be aware that your algorithm won't work, if query parameters are present. You might also want to look at properly handling optional trailing slashes.

Ideally, in my opinion, you would want to provide consistent URLs to the outside world, without any need for redirection. Your URL handling would then internally resolve them to their respective resources, serving the canonical URL on every page load.